# Connect router to PC, as if it were the ISP of the router

Tags: networking, router, intranet

I'm very new to networking and especially the hardware part of the networks, but I started working on something for which I don't have enough knowledge, but hopefully this is an opportunity to learn.

Is it possible to connect a PC to a router in such a way that the PC looks like the ISP to the router?

Intuitively, I connected the WAN port to the PC, instead of the LAN one, but I don't know how to interact with it.

I guess I need high level access to the firmwere of the router.

Comment: Config will need to occur on the PC telling it that it needs to be servicing a network through that network port. If you're trying to pass through internet from an internet service the PC accesses some other way, you'll need to set up a Bridge. Otherwise, basic setup will be that the PC needs to be running a DHCP server on the port the router is connected to. This isn't an unknown config though, so what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: There's also a LOT of questions on this site regarding this, in various forms. You should review those along with other research you do on your own: https://superuser.com/search?q=share+internet+from+pc

Comment: the router probably expects the PC to issue an IP address ... try running a DHCP server on the PC